# Sitecore Publish creates corrupt item

Tags: sitecore, publish

I have this piece of code below which I am using to publish to the web database. I am having an issue where when I publish with the code below I have a corrupt item in the web database which when I click on gives me the error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name 'item''. When I look at the item the icon for it is that of the standard template vs the custom template which has a custom icon. But when I click on it I saw all the fields and also the above mentioned error.

Could having an item with the same name as the published item in the web database be an issue?

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    Sitecore.Data.Database target = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem(new ID(id));
    Sitecore.Data.Database[] targetDatabases = { target };
    Sitecore.Globalization.Language[] languages = master.Languages;
    bool deep = false;
    bool compareRevisions = true;
    Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishItem(home, targetDatabases, languages, deep, compareRevisions);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the template that the item is based on exists in the 'web' database?

Comment: Yes the template exists. This problem doesn't occur on every publish for every item. It happens for some items only.

Comment: Does it also occur if you publish it manually from Sitecore (not from code)?

Comment: No, the manual publishing works fine without any problems.

Comment: When I go into the web database and hit 'reset' from the presentation tab the item becomes all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If related to the context your are publishing in*

## Async publishing

You could try to run the publishing job asynchronously.
The publishing is then done through a Sitecore job.

```
using Sitecore.Publishing;
PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions(item.Database, Database.GetDatabase("web"), PublishMode.SingleItem, item.Language, DateTime.Now) { Deep = deep, RootItem = item };

Publisher p = new Publisher(publishOptions);
p.PublishAsync();
```

*If this does not make any difference it could be related to an invalid field value left in the items values table.*

## Database cleanup

You could try a Database Cleanup and remove old field for a start and if still causing problems You should take a look at the value fields in the database level and compare field values on a "wrong" publish and a correct publish.